# AttributeError after getting hit in Alien Invasion game

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I'm done my Alien Invasion game but if I get hit once, I get this error:

```
    game_functions.py, line 182 in ship_hit
        sb.prep_ships()
    AttribueError: 'pygame.Surface' objecthas no attribute 'prep_ships'
```

Here is the section of error in game_functions

```
    def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, sb, ship, aliens, bullets):
        """Respond to the ship being hit by an alien."""
        if stats.ships_left > 0:
            # Decrement ships_left.
            stats.ships_left -= 1
    
            # Update scoreboard.
            # Here is the error.
            sb.prep_ships()

            # Empty the list of aliens and bullets.
            aliens.empty()
            bullets.empty()

            # Create a new fleet and center the ship.
            create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
            ship.center_ship()

            # Pause.
            sleep(0.5)
    
        else:
            stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
            
    def check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, sb, ship, aliens, bullets):
        """Check if any aliens have reached the bottom of the screen."""
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom:
                # Treat the same as if the ship got hit.
                ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, sb, ship, aliens, bullets)
                break
```

Here is scoreboard.py:

```
import pygame.font
from pygame.sprite import Group

from ship import Ship

class Scoreboard():
    """A class to report scoring information."""
    
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, stats):
        """Initialize scorekeeping attributes."""
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.ai_settings = ai_settings
        self.stats = stats
        
        # Font settings for scoring information.
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
        
        # Prepare the initial score images.
        self.prep_score()
        self.prep_high_score()
        self.prep_level()
        self.prep_ships()
        
    def prep_score(self):
        """Turn the score into a rendered image."""
        rounded_score = int(round(self.stats.score, -1))
        score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)
        score_str = str(self.stats.score)
        self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True, self.text_color, self.ai_settings.bg_color)
        
        # Display the score at the top right of the screen.
        self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
        self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
        self.score_rect.top = 20
        
    def prep_high_score(self):
        """Turn the high score into a rendered image."""
        high_score = int(round(self.stats.high_score, -1))
        high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
        self.high_score_image = self.font.render(high_score_str, True, self.text_color, self.ai_settings.bg_color)
        
        # Center the high score at the top of the screen.
        self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
        self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top
        
    def prep_level(self):
        """Turn the level into a rendered image."""
        self.level_image = self.font.render(str(self.stats.level), True, self.text_color, self.ai_settings.bg_color)
        
        # Position the level below the score.
        self.level_rect = self.level_image.get_rect()
        self.level_rect.right = self.score_rect.right
        self.level_rect.top = self.score_rect.bottom + 10
        
    def prep_ships(self):
        """Show how many ships are left."""
        self.ships = Group()
        for ship_number in range(self.stats.ships_left):
            ship = Ship(self.ai_settings, self.screen)
            ship.rect.x = 10 + ship_number * ship.rect.width
            ship.rect.y = 10
            self.ships.add(ship)
        
    def show_score(self):
        """Draw scores and ships to the screen."""
        self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
        self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
        # Draw ships.
        self.ships.draw(self.screen)
```

alien_invasion.py:

```
    import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Group

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from scoreboard import Scoreboard
from button import Button
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf

def run_game():
    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
        (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

# Make the Play button.
play_button = Button(ai_settings, screen, "Play")

# Create an instance to store game statistics and create a scoreboard.
stats = GameStats(ai_settings)
sb = Scoreboard(ai_settings, screen, stats)

# Make a ship, a group of bullets, and a group of aliens.
ship = Ship(ai_settings, screen)
bullets = Group()
aliens = Group()

# Create the fleet of aliens.
gf.create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
    
# Start the main loop for the game.
while True:
    gf.check_events(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, play_button, ship, aliens, bullets)
    
    if stats.game_active:
        ship.update()
        gf.update_bullets(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets)
        gf.update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, sb, ship, aliens, bullets)
        
    gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, stats, sb, ship, aliens, bullets, play_button)
            
run_game()
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
"""A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

def __init__(self):
    """Initialize the game's static settings."""
    # Screen settings
    self.screen_width = 1200
    self.screen_height = 600
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
    
    # Ship settings
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
    self.ship_limit = 3
    
    # Bullet settings
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 3
    self.bullet_width = 3
    self.bullet_height = 15
    self.bullet_color = 200, 0, 0
    self.bullets_allowed = 3
    
    # Alien settings
    self.fleet_drop_speed = 10
    
    # How quickly the game speeds up
    self.speedup_scale = 1.1
    # How quickly the alien point values increase
    self.score_scale = 1.5
    
    self.initialize_dynamic_settings()
    
def initialize_dynamic_settings(self):
    """Initialize settings that change through the game."""
    self.ship_speed_factor = 1.5
    self.bullet_speed_factor = 3
    self.alien_speed_factor = 1
    
    # fleet_direction of 1 represents right; -1 represents left.
    self.fleet_direction = 1
    
    # Scoring
    self.alien_points = 50
    
def increase_speed(self):
    """Increase speed settings and alien point values."""
    self.ship_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.bullet_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    self.alien_speed_factor *= self.speedup_scale
    
    self.alien_points = int(self.alien_points * self.score_scale)
```

ship.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Ship(Sprite):

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
    """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
    super(Ship, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    
    # Load the ship image and get its rect.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    
    # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen.
    self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.rect.bottom = self.screen_rect.bottom
    
    # Store a decimal value for the ship's center.
    self.center = float(self.rect.centerx)
    
    # Movement flags
    self.moving_right = False
    self.moving_left = False
    
def update(self):
    """Update the ship's position based on movement flags."""
    # Update the ship's center value, not the rect.
    if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
        self.center += self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
    if self.moving_left and self.rect.left > 0:
        self.center -= self.ai_settings.ship_speed_factor
        
    # Update rect object from self.center.
    self.rect.centerx = self.center
    
def blitme(self):
    """Draw the ship at its current location."""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    
def center_ship(self):
    """Center the ship on the screen."""
    self.center = self.screen_rect.centerx
```

bullet.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Bullet(Sprite):
    """A class to manage bullets fired from the ship"""

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, ship):
    """Create a bullet object at the ship's current position."""
    super().__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    
    # Create a bullet rect at (0, 0) and then set the correct position.
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, 
        ai_settings.bullet_height)
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top
    
    # Store the bullet's position as a decimal value.
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)
    
    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update(self):
    """Move the bullet up the screen."""
    # Update the decimal position of the bullet.
    self.y -= self.speed_factor
    # Update the rect position.
    self.rect.y = self.y
    
def draw_bullet(self):
    """Draw the bullet to the screen."""
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

alien.py:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    """A class to represent a single alien in the fleet."""

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
    """Intialize the alien and set its starting position."""
    super(Alien, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    
    # Load the alien image and set its rect attribute.
    self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    
    # Start each new alien near the top left of the screen.
    self.rect.x = self.rect.width
    self.rect.y = self.rect.height
    
    # Store the alien's exact position.
    self.x = float(self.rect.x)
    
def blitme(self):
    """Draw the alien at its current position."""
    self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
    
def check_edges(self):
    """Return True if alien is at edge of screen."""
    screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    if self.rect.right >= screen_rect.right:
        return True
    elif self.rect.left <= 0:
        return True
    
def update(self):
    """Move the alien right or left."""
    self.x += (self.ai_settings.alien_speed_factor * 
                    self.ai_settings.fleet_direction)
    self.rect.x = self.x
```

game_stats.py:

```
class GameStats():
"""Track statistics for Alien Invasion."""

def __init__(self, ai_settings):
    """Initialize statistics."""
    self.ai_settings = ai_settings
    self.reset_stats()
    
    # Start game in an inactive state.
    self.game_active = False
    # High score should never be reset.
    self.high_score = 0
    
def reset_stats(self):
    """Initialize statistics that can change during the game."""
    self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
    self.score = 0
    self.level = 1
```

button.py:

```
class Button():

def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen, msg):
    """Initialize button attributes."""
    self.screen = screen
    self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    
    # Set the dimensions and properties of the button.
    self.width, self.height = 200, 50
    self.button_color = (0, 0, 0)
    self.text_color = (255, 255, 255)
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)
    
    # Build the button's rect object and center it. 
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
    self.rect.center = self.screen_rect.center
    
    # The button message needs to be prepped only once.
    self.prep_msg(msg)
    
def prep_msg(self, msg):
    """Turn msg into a rendered image and center text on the button."""
    self.msg_image = self.font.render(msg, True, self.text_color, self.button_color)
    self.msg_image_rect = self.msg_image.get_rect()
    self.msg_image_rect.center = self.rect.center
    
def draw_button(self):
    # Draw blank button and then draw message.
    self.screen.fill(self.button_color, self.rect)
    self.screen.blit(self.msg_image, self.msg_image_rect)
```

**Edit:**
There is an indenting problem from after copy and pasting it.
Theres no indent problems in the actual code.

That's all the coding, sorry if its alot. But this is everything with the game.

Comment: error is saying `sb` object doesn't have `prep_ships()` method

Comment: SB is short for scoreboard. I can add the scoreboard file if u need it

Comment: yeah add it and also add also add code for how you you creating `scoreboard` object

Comment: i didnt include them but these are the rest of the files: alien_invasion.py(this is the file that I excecute), settings.py, bullet.py, alien.py, game_stats.py, ship.py, and button.py

Comment: you said `sb` is `Scoreboard` objects but in error it's showing `sb` is a `pygame.Surface`

Comment: I'm not too sure why. I can send all the code if you want

Comment: Has anyone figured it out yet?